# Drywall repair with cut wall studs

Tags: drywall, basement, studs

We've just had a french drain installed around our basement. In a couple of places, it was necessary to open a hole in a (non-load-bearing) wall, leaving both a hole in the drywall and a cut stud:

[image]

I think we know how to handle the drywall repair ourselves, but first we need to repair the stud so that we have something to which to attach the drywall.  What's the correct way to do that for such a small area?

Would we do something like this?

[image]

And if that's the right approach, can we use something like construction adhesive to attach the replacement baseplate to the concrete floor?

Comment: How big is the hole, to the edge of the existing drywall? 6" wide x 8" high?

Comment: It's about 8x12 measuring at the widest spots

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your proposed solution is perfect. I'd suggest using pressure treated wood in contact with the concrete. Adhesive probably won't work terribly well, but if you get a couple of screws in on an angle on the right (connecting to the old plate) plus lots of screws elsewhere, everything should hold together well enough to carry drywall.

Answer (score 1):

Given what looks like black mold on the lower portion of the other drywall I'd be tempted to cut a large rectangle.  I'd probably opt for the paper free green board that can't mold.  The sheet will be 4x8 so I'd pull back a 8' section along the bottom and cut it to the height of the current hole.  Keep the drywall 1/4" off the concrete.  Your plan for 2x4 nailers is fine.  After you drywall - I go with a vinyl facia type of baseboard that is water proof.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about keeping the drywall off the floor; I hadn't thought about that.

Answer (score 0):

A little *too* perfect; it'll be protected by trim. It could just be a 2x4 screwed to the surface of the stud and one to the floor plate. And maybe a floating one in the top right. Cut the hole square first.